# TikZ is incompatible with a specific style file

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, thesis

I am using [a custom style file for my thesis](http://buam.iyte.edu.tr/LaTeX/iyte.sty).

My figures heavily depend on the awesome TikZ package. However, even if I only add the line

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

to [the sample thesis](http://buam.iyte.edu.tr/LaTeX/Sample_Thesis.tex), I get countless errors. For example:

*! LaTeX error: \begin{figure} on input line 458 ended by \end{origfigure}.*

I have never had problems with the TikZ package or the thesis style file separately. I have tried to change the style file but I could not get rid of the errors.

Comment: Do the pictures as standalone files and include the resulting pdf. Saves compiling time as well.

Comment: Remove the `origfigure` and `origtable` parts. It is just automating the figure with the default `[htb]` arguments and adding some spacing+centering. There are much better ways to do it. And you can define your own environment.

Comment: To get automatic centering for figures and tables I'd use `\makeatletter
 \g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother` instead of these strange redefinitions in your style file.

Comment: The style redefines an internal float command (`\@xfloat`) in a way that is not color-safe. At soon as a color package is loaded it breaks.

Comment: Wow. I was nearly going to give up asking this very specific question. We have an excellent community here. Thank you for the wise advice!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The style is redefining `\@xfloat` but misses the color commands. Try this patch:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{iyte}
\makeatletter
\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{\ifhmode \@bsphack\@floatpenalty -\@Mii\else
   \@floatpenalty-\@Miii\fi\def\@captype{#1}\ifinner
      \@parmoderr\@floatpenalty\z@
    \else\@next\@currbox\@freelist{\@tempcnta\csname ftype@#1\endcsname
       \multiply\@tempcnta\@xxxii\advance\@tempcnta\sixt@@n
       \@tfor \@tempa :=#2\do
                        {\if\@tempa h\advance\@tempcnta \@ne\fi
                         \if\@tempa t\advance\@tempcnta \tw@\fi
                         \if\@tempa b\advance\@tempcnta 4\relax\fi
                         \if\@tempa p\advance\@tempcnta 8\relax\fi
         }\global\count\@currbox\@tempcnta}\@fltovf\fi
    \global\setbox\@currbox
      \color@vbox %<--- missing
      \normalcolor %<----missing
      \vbox\bgroup
    \def\baselinestretch{1}
    \ifx\undefined\selectfont
    \small\normalsize
    \else
    \@newbaseline
    \fi
    \boxmaxdepth\z@
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore}
 \makeatother   
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
blub
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```